# how to create a Google Tag Manager trigger for an anchor #id click

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am using Elegant Themes' Divi Wordpress theme, which prevents anchors from being appended to the current browser address when clicked.

This means I can't track a click to our /#contact form using History State change in Google Tag Manager.

What I'd like to do is create a Trigger for a click on an anchor with `id="contact-us"`. i.e. a click on `<a href="#contact" id="contact-us"><img src="something"></a>`

How do I do this in Google Tag Manager please?

Answer (score 0):

Trigger "Click - All Elements" and use your `id` (and Page URL if it's neseccary).

[image]

Comment: Should also work with a link only trigger when validation is disabled (usually the link only trigger would consider an anchor a valid link target, so you need to switch validation off).